# jqGrid: Center entire grid on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I'm fairly new to jqGrid and was wondering how to format the entire jqgrid to be in the center of the page. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241102/how-to-center-a-jqgrid) where they suggested including a snippet of code in the jqgrid css file but when I tried that the grid is not responsive to any changes I make.

I was wondering if there was a different way to center the grid on the page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your rendered Html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By **Center entire grid on page**, I guess you want to position the grid to center of the page and not align the text centered in the grid, if so, Just wrap your `<table>` tags in a `<div>` tag, and use `align=center` like,

```
<div align="center"> 
    <table id = "jQGrid"></table>
</div>
```

Hope i didn't misunderstand your question.