# Cannot center the jqGrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I tried to add the code below to the grid.css but still cannot center the jqGrid. Any amendment can make the jqGrid to center?

```
.center { width: 640px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

or

```
.center .ui-jqgrid {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

The above codes I'm reference from [How to center a JqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241102/how-to-center-a-jqgrid)

Part of my grid.css:

```
.GridHeader {
}
.Header {
width: 100%;
}
.Header th { 
font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;
padding: 2px;
background-image: url(images/headerbg.gif) ;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.HeaderLeft { 
background-image: url(images/headerleft.gif);
}
.HeaderRight { 
background-image: url(images/headerright.gif);
}
.HeaderButton {
background-image: url(images/headerbg.gif); 
}
.HeaderButton img{
width: 17px;
}
.HeaderLeft img{
width: 14px;
}
.HeaderRight img{
width: 10px;
}
.GridHeader table {margin:0;}
.GridHeader td, tr {padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you made small error in your tests. The usage of `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` is very easy. It's important that the CSS styles are applied only on the div having fixed `width` value. If you use for example the following HTML fragment for jqGrid

```html
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

then during creating of the grid from the table `#list` many other outer dives and tables will be created on the place of `<table id="list"></table>`. The most outer div from the constructs will be the div having some fixed width, the class `"ui-jqgrid"` and the id constructed from `gbox_` prefix and the id of the grid. In case of `id="list"` used for the table the outer div will get id="gbox_list". So to cetner the grid you can use **one** from the following CSS styles:

```css
.ui-jqgrid { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

or

```css
#gbox_list { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

You can apply the same styles if you place `<table id="list"></table>` inside of some outer div like below

```html
<div class="mycenter">
    <table id="list"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

and allying the CSS rule

```css
.mycenter > .ui-jqgrid { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

All the above approaches will work. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterGrid.htm) shows it live.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Oleg . I tried your methods but still cannot center the grid. I checked the div width is fixed.

Comment: @Jennifer: You can see on [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterGrid.htm) that the grid are centered. If you have another case then either the required CSS rules are not applied or some another CSS rules overwrite the styles. You should prepare the demo which shows your problem. You can use jsfiddle.net for example.

Comment: I had asked my friend and he help me to solved the problem.
The solution is so simple as showed below:
<code>
<center>
    <table id="list"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</center>
</code>